# Как получать значения из списка по условию?

Tags: python, datetime

Есть список:

```
a = ['12.05.2020', '16.05.2020', '12.05.2019', '19.05.2019', '20.05.2019',
     '19.05.2020', '22.05.2020', '27.05.2020', '14.05.2020', '25.05.2019']
```

И есть переменная с годом: `b = '2020'`

Надо из списка a получить самую маленькую дату с этим годом.

Результат должен быть таким: `12.05.2020`

Comment: покажите как вы пытались это сделать

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
min(d for d in map(lambda i: datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%d.%m.%Y'), filter(lambda el: el.split('.')[-1] == '2020', a)) if isinstance(d, datetime.date))
```

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
from datetime import datetime

res = min((x for x in a if x.endswith(".2020")), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

Comment: Лексикографический порядок тоже бы подошёл.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, если сравнивать лексикографически то 01.12.2020 будет меньше чем 10.12.2025